# Android devices not receiving 5% of push sent with Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

The graph below from Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) Console shows how only ~95% of our push are being received by the phones. This is causing lots of issues for us as we're creating a VoIP app and need the push to be received immediately. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to get this rate closer to 100%?

Some important notes:

- All phones are Android
- All phones had our app open at the time they received the push or up to 2 minutes prior
- All push are data push (i.e. no body/title) with priority high
- The push is sent with expiration 10 seconds to prioritize them following Android docs
- We had ~30 errors (registration-token-not-registered and internal-error) sending push in the same period, which is nothing compared to the ~500 undelivered push

[image: Screenshot from FCM Console]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pir,

As far as I understand, there are many reasons why a message might not be delivered. I think without looking at your specific data, it is going to be difficult for anyone to give a conclusive answer.

What I do recommend is that you spend some time reading [Understanding message delivery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery) on the Firebase Documentation. Although I recommend you read the entire article, of particular interst for you will probably be the [BigQuery data export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#bigquery-data-export) section. This covers exporting your message data to BigQuery. Data exported to BigQuery is covered in the [What data is exported to BigQuery?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#what-data-exported) section. I think you're going to be interested in the `event` field which holds data about the type of event that occurred. These events types include:

- MESSAGE_ACCEPTED: the message was received by the FCM server and the request is valid;
- MESSAGE_DELIVERED: the message has been delivered to the app's FCM SDK on the device. By default, this field is not propagrated. To enable, follow the instructions provided in [`setDeliveryMetricsExportToBigQuery(boolean)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging#public-void-setdeliverymetricsexporttobigquery-boolean-enable)).
- MISSING_REGISTRATIONS: the request was rejected due to a missing registration;
- UNAUTHORIZED_REGISTRATION: the message was rejected because the sender is not authorized to send to the registration;
- MESSAGE_RECEIVED_INTERNAL_ERROR: there was an unspecified error when processing the message request;
- MISMATCH_SENDER_ID: the request to send a message was rejected due to a mismatch between the sender id sending the message, and the one declared for the end-point;
- QUOTA_EXCEEDED: the request to send a message was rejected due to insufficient quota;
- INVALID_REGISTRATION: the request to send a message was rejected due to an invalid registration;
- INVALID_PACKAGE_NAME: the request to send a message was rejected due to an invalid package name;
- INVALID_APNS_CREDENTIAL: the request to send a message was rejected due to an invalid APNS certificate;
- INVALID_PARAMETERS: the request to send a message was rejected due to invalid parameters;
- PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE: the request to send a message was rejected due to a payload larger than the limit;
- AUTHENTICATION_ERROR: the request to send a message was rejected due to an authentication error (check the API Key used to send the message);
- INVALID_TTL: the request to send a message was rejected due to an invalid TTL.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I tried this. However, the only events we get are `MESSAGE_ACCEPTED` and 14 `MESSAGE_RECEIVED_INTERNAL_ERROR` events corresponding to the errors I mentioned in my original post. We'll add the code needed for `MESSAGE_DELIVERED`, but so far this doesn't give us much insight into what's happening. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons that could make notification not delivered.

- There are devices that might have a specific battery optimization that will stop notifications from showing.
  And to fix that you might ask user to do the following.
  check <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Battery</kbd> > <kbd>Battery Optimization or Adaptive Battery</kbd> > Find your app and press <kbd>Don't optimize</kbd>
- The app has might push permissions Disabled
  In Device Settings, user can turn **on** and **off** push notifications. From notification setting under <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Apps</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

- *All phones had our app open at the time they received the push or up 
  to 2 minutes prior*

How do you know that all phones are on and not is sleepmode ? Are you 100% sure ?

- *All push are data push (i.e. no body/title) with priority high The    push is sent with expiration 10 seconds to prioritize them following   Android docs*

I also use data FCM to coordinate updates between devices, in my case the vast majority of messages are received in less than 1/2 second but sometimes I have observed that they are delayed up to about 20 seconds and then several are received suddenly.

With a TimeToLive of only 10 seconds in your case they would be lost.

Also Google claims that 95% of the messages are delivered in fewer than 250 milliseconds, but the remaining 5% does not, that would already justify those lose.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try increasing the time-to-live!

Comment: We know that they were open at that time or 2 minutes before because we only allow recently-online users to be called.